# What are the specifications required to install Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

As every operating system has certain system requirements, what is the minimum specification required to install Windows 8.

Comment: This would be best researched at the MS site, but here is a wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8#PCs

Comment: Windows 8 System Requirements
http://www.pcrequirements.net/en/softwares/windows-8-system-requirements/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's probably 3 things you need to look at. Firstly there's a hard list of system requirements -

Any system that would run windows 7 would run windows 8 comfortably -

```
Processor: 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster
RAM: 1 gigabyte (GB) (32-bit) or 2 GB (64-bit)
Hard disk space: 16 GB (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)
Graphics card: Microsoft DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM driver
```

Secondly there's also additional requirements for certain features : multitouch for touch screen features, and a monitor of 1024x768 resolution for using Windows Store/Modern Applications, and 1366x768 to be able to 'snap' apps

Both these are off the [windows 8 enterprise evaluation page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/)

If you wanted a idea of what would * definitely* work, you [might want to take a look at the systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/experiencing-windows-8-touch-on-windows-7-hardware) that MS used to test windows 8 as well.

You can still use the old [windows 8 consumer preview setup file](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=242045) to check compatibility on an older system running windows to be sure as well, until a release version comes out.

This should give you an overview of what exactly is likely to give you issues if you do update. As of October 2012, the setup will will check your hardware and software but not do an install, and is pretty small

I've run this on an old XP system from 2007 (which is apparently fully compatible with windows 8!) and it clearly tells me which applications and hardware would need fixing.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Why not [Google](https://www.google.com/) it? [First link shows up from Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-requirements).

> ## System requirements
>
> **Windows 8.1**
>
> If you want to run Windows 8.1 on your PC, here's what it takes:
>
> - **Processor**: 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster with support for PAE, NX, and    SSE2 (more info)
> - **RAM**: 1 gigabyte (GB) (32-bit) or 2 GB (64-bit)
> - **Hard disk space**: 16 GB (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)
> - **Graphics card**: Microsoft DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM driver
>
> **Windows 8**
>
> If you want to run Windows 8 on your PC, here's what it takes:
>
> - **Processor**: 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster with support for PAE, NX, and    SSE2 (more info)
> - **RAM**: 1 gigabyte (GB) (32-bit) or 2 GB (64-bit)
> - **Hard disk space**: 16 GB (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)
> - **Graphics card**: Microsoft DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM driver

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft recommends:

```
1 GHz or faster processor
1 GB RAM (32-bit) or 2 GB RAM (64-bit)
16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)
DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM 1.0 or higher driver
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft states your computer will need the following specifications. Do note that Metro apps won't work on a screen resolution below 1,024x768 pixels.

Windows 8 Release Preview works great on the same hardware that powers Windows 7:

```
Processor: 1GHz or faster.  
RAM: 1GB (32-bit) or 2GB (64-bit).  
Hard disk space: 16GB (32-bit) or 20GB (64-bit).  
Graphics card: Microsoft DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM driver.
```

Additional requirements to use certain features:

> To use touch, you need a tablet or a monitor that supports multi-touch.
>
> To access the Windows Store and to download and run
> apps, you need an active Internet connection and a screen resolution
> of at least 1,024x768 pixels.
>
> Internet access.