# Tool for Windows 7 to check software compatibility before upgrading to Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, compatibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the specifications required to install Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/490847/what-are-the-specifications-required-to-install-windows-8)

Is there a standalone version of the program compatibility wizard that can be used on a recent Windows system to check if a program has know compatibility problems with Windows 8. For example, to check if Adobe Indesign CS5.5 is (in)compatible with Windows 8?

The official kit seems to be at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7352

> mitigate application compatibility issues before deploying Windows 7®,
>   Windows Vista®, a Windows Update

and doesn't mention Windows 8...

Answer (score 3):

> In our testing, we have found no significant issues with running
>   CS5.5, CS6, or Acrobat products with Windows 8.

**[Adobe's compatibility page](http://www.adobe.com/products/indesign/faq.html#windows)**

In general, if you want to check compatibility, use the **[Windows Compatibility](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/win8/CompatCenter/Home?Language=en-US)** page, which carries a community rating as well.

If you want a standalone tool, there is also the **[Upgrade Assistant](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-to-windows-8)** from Microsoft which can generate a report of all installed software and possible incompatibilities with Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

When I downloaded the Windows 8 Upgrade I got a program that checked compatibility (Windows 8 Upgrade Advisor or something like that it was called) and only afterwards purchased and downloaded the actual Windows installation.